# How to list the messages of a nats jetstream and know if they were acknowledged?

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-streaming-server, nats-jetstream

I need to list the messages that were posted in nats stream to know which ones were not recognized.

I have tried to look at the [admin api](https://docs.nats.io/reference/reference-protocols/nats_api_reference) that nats suggests in its documentation, but it does not specify if this can be done or not.

I have also looked at the jetstream [library for go](https://github.com/nats-io/jsm.go), with this I can get general information about the streams and their comsumers but not the messages that were not acknowledged and I don't see any functions that give me what I need.

Has anyone already done this no matter the programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledgements are tied to a specific `consumer`, not a `stream`.

You can derive the state of acknowledgements from `consumer` info, precisely, the Acknowledgement floor:

```
nats consumer info
```

```
State:

   Last Delivered Message: Consumer sequence: 8 Stream sequence: 158 Last delivery: 13m59s ago
     Acknowledgment floor: Consumer sequence: 4 Stream sequence: 154 Last Ack: 13m59s ago
         Outstanding Acks: 2 out of maximum 1,000
     Redelivered Messages: 0
     Unprocessed Messages: 42
            Waiting Pulls: 0 of maximum 512
```

Which is available in NATS CLI and most client libraries.
There is no way to directly see the list of acknowledged messages.